# How Should I Handle This IndexOutOfBounds Exception?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception

I have some code below, and in some very obscure cases the fromIndex variable is set to -1:

```
int fromIndex = 0;
if (newCurrentPeriod != null) {
    // Guard in case we are rolling back to before the start of the event.
    fromIndex = allPeriods.indexOf(newCurrentPeriod);
}  
for (Period resetPeriod : allPeriods.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)) {
    ...
}
```

Currently, if `fromIndex is -1`, the `ArrayList class will throw an IndexOutOfBounds Exception within the sublistRangeCheck method`.

**My queries :**

How best should I handle this exception within our code? Should I surround it with a try catch, print the stack trace and log some additional information for debugging purposes? Should I defensively check that the fromPeriod is >= 0 before executing the for loop and if not log some information?

How would you/what is the best practise for handling scenarios like this in your code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's default that you want to do if fromIndex goes to -1? Should you default to 0 or return from there etc etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally catching an IndexOutOfBounds(RuntimeException) is not a good practice.

A runtime exception is an exception that occurs which probably could have been avoided by the programmer.

A runtime exception should be caught only at the end of the complete operation just for displaying a message to the user that an error has occurred.

Moreover runtime exception won't be identified at compile time and if you could identify the probability of the exception by just a small check(like null check for NullPointer, index check for IndexOutofBounds), it is a best practice which reduces an overhead on the JVM.

Adding a check for fromIndex == -1 would be better way and log the details at which iteration it has occurred.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's bad practice please?

Answer (score 0):

For those obscure scenarios, I would prefer a check before it goes to the method.

```
int fromIndex = 0;
    if (newCurrentPeriod != null) {
        // Guard in case we are rolling back to before the start of the event.
        fromIndex = allPeriods.indexOf(newCurrentPeriod);
    }  
if (fromIndex>=0)
    for (Period resetPeriod : allPeriods.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)) {
        ...
    }
else syso("print something");
```

Answer (score -1):

indexOf is part of the List Interface and the definition in the docs says:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

> Returns: the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element

And more exactly:

> More formally, returns the highest index i such that (o==null ?
>   get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

This means that when you get an index of -1 the object you are looking for doesn't exist in the list.

Did You implmenented a custom "equals" method in your object? If not, the List Impl. is using the instance id of the objects to match them, this means two instances of that object including same data are still diferent because they are not the same instance!

So if you are sure that the object you are looking for is in the list then check your "equals" method or implement one which compares your object based on the input not the instance.

If it is possible that the searched object isn't in the list, then you only have to handle the case that you don't need to get a sublist.

```
if (formIndex >= 0) {
        for (Period resetPeriod : allPeriods.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)) {
            ...
        }
}
```